# How would one term this particular relationship between "Bill Gates" and "Bill Gateaux"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

While postulating a French universe, my brain voted that Bill Gates should become Bill Gateaux.

What term or short-phrase would one use to describe the word 'Gateaux', relative to 'Gates', where the meaning is irrelevant? Is there a term that describes such relationships?

I know that there is a reason my brain linked these two words. As far as I can tell, it's a semi-random phenomenon, and I have no particular reason to believe that these two words should be linked together.

Comment: _If_ it would be phonetically close, the relation could be described as _homophonic_. However, I fail to see the phonetic link here; you added a complete syllable to his name. _Guaites_ would come a lot closer. (I'd opt for keeping the semantics and go with Guillaume Portes, but I'm not a writer.)

Comment: This *is* the problem. I really don't know how to describe this particular relationship!

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not even sure I understand what relationship you mean. If you mean "adding a French-sounding suffix to a name", I'm not sure there is a name for it...

Comment: I can tell you that it's not about adding a French sounding suffix.

Comment: I vote for "Frenchified", or better yet: "French fried".

Comment: You might try a langue d’oc instead of a langue d’oïl (which are two broad branches of "French" languages; think Provençal). So for example *William* could be *Guilhèm* in Occitan, while *Gates* could be *Pòrtas*. That would make him a bit more interesting than run-of-the-mill French. :) On peut trouver [un dictionnaire français–occitan en ligne ici](https://fr.glosbe.com/fr/oc/).

Comment: So you're asking what you call a verbal confection made from an original word which has nothing to do with the result?

Comment: 'You need to popularize this word.' 'You need to post this as an answer.' You're confusing your desires with others' needs.

Comment: I am already starting to think of him as *Bill Cakes*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have said that the link was an ***onomatopoeic*** one. It is based entirely on the closeness of sound, as opposed to meaning.

***Onomatopoeia*** is defined as 'the formation of a word from a sound associated with what it is named'. Usually that 'sound' is a natural sound e.g. *cuckoo* or *sizzle*. But I see no reason why it shouldn't be another word, especially one in a different language.

Based on meaning I suppose in France he might be known as *Guillaume Portes*.

Comment: The example in the question is much closer in how it's spelled than how it sounds.

Comment: I suppose what I was trying to say is that I get the feeling that the OP was trying to pick an existing word that kind of looked similar in writing rather than write something that would *sound* the same if pronounced in French.

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in a private language answer: my family would say, "That's very [Mots d'Heures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mots_d'Heures)", after the brilliant book written by Luis D'Antin Van Rooten.

Answer (score 2):

If the first term makes you think of the second term, you could describe it as *[evocative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evocative)*

> bringing thoughts, memories, or feelings into the mind

*Merriam-Webster*

Comment: You do have specific thoughts: gates and gateaux start with the same four letters.

Answer (score 1):

If your brain votes for things, then you are using [Free association](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_association_%28psychology%29). From the cited page:

> The method of free association has no linear or preplanned agenda, but works by intuitive leaps and linkages which may lead to new personal insights and meanings: 'the logic of association is a form of unconscious thinking'

So perhaps you could say

> In my reverie, I free-associated Bill Gates, and my subconscious came up with Guillaume Gateaux.

Answer (score 1):

"Faux amis" or "false cognates" might be applicable. This expression applies to words whose similarity lies only in their structure, sound, and/or letter sequences. My French mum always uses it when people try really direct translations that result in real French/English words having meanings completely different from that intended.

Answer (score 1):

It is a **[malapropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism)**:

> A malapropism is the use of an incorrect word in place of a word with
>   a similar sound, resulting in a nonsensical, often humorous utterance.
>   An example is Yogi Berra's statement: "Texas has a lot of electrical
>   votes," rather than "electoral votes".

More examples include Archie Bunker calling Orthodox Jews "off-the-docks Jews", referring to "the Women's Lubrication Movement" rather than Liberation and "Peach 'n cake" instead of Piece of Cake.

Comment: What you're describing is a *verbal* quirk, limited to speech only. Thanks for sharing a new word though.

Comment: @VatsalManot No, it is not limited to speech. Modern writers make use of malapropisms in novels and cartoons. Everything on EL&U is verbal. *Verbal* pertains to language in general, as opposed to say, *mathematical*.